# difference between cp

Tags: linux, bash, unix

There are two parentdirs A and B with many subdirs and files. While sitting in parentdir B, typing these two commands; What is the difference between them ?

```
cp -r /path/to/A/* *
```

and

```
cp -r /path/to/A/* .
```

Comment: `cp -r /path/to/A/* * ` is not even correct, if the directory `A` has more than one files or dirs.

Comment: @vidit ... although it will work (and do horrible things that were not intended) if the last item expanded by the `*` at the end happens to be a directory...

Answer (score 2):

You would never type the first command unless you were reckless:

`*` on its own expands to the name of every non-hidden file/directory in the current directory.  So let's assume that `/path/to/A` contains two subdirectories (`spoon` and `fork`), and the current directory contains three subdirectories (`foo`, `bar` and `baz`).  This means the shell would interpret your first command as:

```
cp -r /path/to/A/fork /path/to/A/spoon bar baz foo
```

In other words, recursively copy `/path/to/A/fork`, `/path/to/A/spoon`, `bar` and `baz` into `foo` (the item in the current directory that happens to come last in alphabetical order).  So you'd end up with four new directories under `foo`: `foo/fork`, `foo/spoon`, `foo/bar` and `foo/baz`.

Your second command would mean to recursively copy `/path/to/A/spoon` and `/path/to/A/fork` into the current directory.  This would create two new subdirectories (`fork` and `spoon`) in the current directory.